# JS/jQuery Styled Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I search here for a good-styled scrollbar, but nothing... Can u offer me something, because I can't place the famous from Internet. I want a simple scrollbar, just a line or smth like that. Please give the example in a whole HTML page (with `<head>`, `<body>` etc. tags).

**Thanks previously!**

Comment: Hello, @vladchooo. Stack Overflow functions best when you have specific programming questions, rather than requests for scripts.

Comment: Here you go http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/basic.html

Comment: @genesis - I know, see what I wrote... I find much, but there is som nay "unneeded" information... And I download 100 files and nothing... Just give it in a simple HTML file, PLEASE!

Answer (score 0):

A well styled scrollbar is the one your browser already renders. Reinventing a component of the browser is usually a lot of work for little gain and, potentially negative usability.

As for styling a browser scrollbar, aside from IE, I do not believe you can, as that's technically outside the DOM. So you'll have to create your own drag/scroll functionality.